# Create new php file everytime new user registers

Tags: php

How can i make it create new php file automatically everytime new user registers.
I have tried this code

```
$way="user/$userName";
if(!file_exists("$way")){
        mkdir("$way", 0755);
}
```

But it only creates new folder not file

Comment: Maybe because it is written to create folders, not files?

Comment: @BogdanBurim  what should i change

Comment: Change 'mkdir("$way", 0755);' to 'file_put_contents($way, "");'

Comment: Look into `fopen()` to create a file that you can write to.

Comment: Nobody mentioned [`touch()`](https://secure.php.net/touch) ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [this out](http://php.net/mkdir). It'll tell you everything about function you are using.

Also, you can use this webpage to find functions that will create new files for you (eg. `file_put_contents`, `fwrite`).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "text text text written to created file\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "Jane Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case you should write something like this:

```
$way="user/$userName";
if(!file_exists($way)){
    file_put_contents($way, "");
    chmod($way, 0755)
}
```

Now you have created the file in that directory and `chmod` ed it.
I highly recommend you not doing this (creating `php` files for users). but if you are gonna do it, make sure you remove special characters `\ / * | : ? " < >` from `$userName` to make sure there would be no problem with file names.

Answer (score 0):

use the `fopen($file_location, "w")` function, [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

```
$way="user/$userName";
if(!file_exists("$way")){
  fopen($way,"w");
}
```